# Angularjs ng-repeat filter property with more than one variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I'm trying to something like

```
<ion-item class="item-icon-right " ng-repeat="project in jsonObj.Projects | filter:projectArea:true:ProjectStatus" type="item-text-wrap" ui-sref="tabs.detail({project:project['Project name']})">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-45">
      <h2>{{project["Project name"]}}</h2>
      <h4>{{project["PM"]}}</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="col col-45"></div>
    <div class="col col-10">
      <span class="badge badge-assertive icon-badge"><i class="ion-ios-arrow-right"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-item>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('App')
 .controller('ProjectsController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $state) {
        $scope.projectArea = $stateParams.area;
        $scope.ProjectStatus = $stateParams.Project_Status;      
  });
```

Data:

```
{PM: "Oommen", Area: "Foods", Project name: "PLuM", Reviewer: "Alex", A&D Start Date: "7-Dec-15"…}$$hashKey: "object:31"A&D End Date: "15-Jan-16"A&D Start Date: "7-Dec-15"Area: "Foods"Build End Date: "TBD"Build Start Date: "TBD"Implementation date: "TBD"PM: "Oommen"Project Status: "Green"Project name: "PLuM"Reviewer: "Alex"SIT End Date: "TBD"SIT Start Date: "TBD"ST End Date: "TBD"ST Start Date: "TBD"Status: "HLD Phase Kickoff. Review to be planned early"}
```

I'm trying filter ng-repeat with **Area** and **Project Status** values. However it filters only based on **Area**. Could you someone help to identify the problem?

Comment: Cascade filters? `project in jsonObj.Projects | filter:projectArea:true | filter:ProjectStatus`

Comment: You can also pass the object to filter:  `arrayOfObjects | filter:{Area: xxx, ProjectStatus: kkk}`

Comment: @JohannesJander its working thank you. Please write it as answer, so that i can accept it.

Comment: @Ram great :) I have made the comment into an answer with a link, so please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [chain filters](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/filters/chaining-filters-together.html):

```
 project in jsonObj.Projects | filter:projectArea:true | filter:ProjectStatus
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Use multiple filters where one filter uses the result of the previous filter (chaining)

   ng-repeat="project in projects | myFirstFilter | mySecondFilter"
2. Pass on the data or object you want to add to the equation to the filter.

   ng-repeat="project in projects | myFirstFilter:myData"

I'd go with the first option because it creates a clear separation of what each filter does. Makes it easier to test as well.

Comment: Why the first option if I may ask?